# Is there a way to have a 'live' buffer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, buffer

I use QGIS (2.10.1) to create buffers around polygons.  I often create a series of buffers, and later need to edit the underlying polygons.  It is frustrating to start from scratch in re-create several buffers based on the changes when this happens.

Is there a way to create a 'live' buffer, that will automatically update to changes made to the parent polygon, or as a second best, a means to replicate with one click, the buffer settings and formatting that you originally created?

Comment: Look forward to seeing other responses to this but the only success I have had is from storing the base data in a postGIS database and dynamically drawing buffers with a view using ST_Buffer. If you cannot use postgresql then your best bet might well be scripting the buffer creation so you can at least regenerate the buffer zones with minimal fuss. I'd use R but there's probably an easier way of scripting it in python within QGIS.

Comment: Quite easy to do if you store your data in PostgreSQL/PostGIS. At least for creating selections, not as sure about actually displaying the buffers.

Comment: Also checkout the QGIS Multi Ring Buffer: http://gisforthought.com/qgis-multi-ring-buffer/ OR the Multi-Distance Buffer https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/MultiDistanceBuffer/

Comment: is it for visualization only or for analysis ?

Comment: @radouxju - usually I'll need to use the buffers to create a layer of intersects between the buffer and other polygons

Comment: @Vesanto - I'll look at those, which are presubly not live, but a simpler way of creating buffers?

Comment: @Tumbledown (and Vesanto's first answer) I don't understand most of the words in your answers, but I'll get on to Google and see if they lead me somewhere.

Comment: I would wrap the buffer tool into a small python script, and connect this script to the layerChanged() Signal. So each time you commit an edit, a new buffer layer will be created. At first the script should delete an existing buffer theme.

Comment: Another vote to storing your base data in PostGIS and using a view to dynamically buffer the geometries.

Answer (score 5):

Posting an answer from another question ([How to add a buffer in QGIS that updates itself](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/253326/how-to-add-a-buffer-in-qgis-that-updates-itself/)) as an alternative to the postgis/rdbms solutions already shared.

For a foolproof, simple visualisation, try the **geometry generator**.

1. Go to Layer Styling panel -> select style -> Symbol layer type: Geometry generator
2. select Geometry type: Polygon/Multipolygon
3. enter the following expression `buffer($geometry,AMOUNT)`
4. AMOUNT can be a fixed number in the units of your CRS, or a field in your data - in which case it would be `buffer($geometry,"buffer_field")`
5. buffers will appear as soon as you add or edit a point in qgis, even if you haven't saved edits

To generate polygons that you can calculate areas of and so on, try **virtual layers**.

1. Go to Layer -> Add Layer -> Add/Edit Virtual Layer
2. click Import and select your layer
3. enter the following query: `SELECT desired_field, desired_field2, 'desired field', st_buffer(geometry,AMOUNT) AS geometry from 'Name of layer';` - desired fields are optional. Any names of layers or fields with spaces, or most non-alphanumeric characters, must be wrapped in single quotes. **Click Test to check that there are no errors before clicking OK**.
4. buffers are saved as a separate layer, which will update only when you press Refresh, and any edits are saved (if editing your source layer outside qgis)

Comment: Maybe providing a link to the mentioned question would be a better approach instead of copy&pasting already given answers. At least to prevent redundancy and allow other users to compare those questions.

Comment: Okay, I added a link to the question (which was marked as a duplicate of this), but I only pasted it here on the request of someone else.

Comment: Great answer. "when you press Refresh" - where is Refresh?

Answer (score 4):

Creating a View in PostGIS to have a "live buffer" is of course the best choice if you are willing to setup a RDBMS.
I was curious to see if you could also get some sort of live buffer without PostGIS, so I gave it a try with spatialite and it works too.
The difference is just that it seems that you can't create a View with a different geometry-type in spatialite.
I found this inforation here:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/spatialite-users/ZZIPwYt8-uA
there was written:

*"there is absolutely no way to show a View 
geometry in spatialite-gis, if the geometry-class isn't 
exactly the same of the one used for the main-table"*

So you have to use a buffer table and three triggers:

```
CREATE TABLE lines ( id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name TEXT NOT NULL);


SELECT AddGeometryColumn('lines', 'geometry', 3857, 'LINESTRING', 'XY');


CREATE TABLE lines_buffer (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, gid INTEGER, name TEXT NOT NULL);

SELECT AddGeometryColumn('lines_buffer', 'geo', 3857, 'POLYGON', 'XY');

CREATE TRIGGER "lines_buffer_insert" AFTER
INSERT ON "lines"
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
INSERT INTO lines_buffer (gid, name, geo)
SELECT new.id,
       new.name,
       ST_Buffer(new.geometry, 1000) ; 
END

CREATE TRIGGER "lines_buffer_update" AFTER
UPDATE ON "lines"
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
UPDATE lines_buffer
SET geo=(ST_Buffer(NEW.geometry, 1000))
WHERE gid=NEW.id ;
  UPDATE lines_buffer
  SET name=NEW.name WHERE gid=NEW.id ; 
END

  CREATE TRIGGER "lines_buffer_delete" AFTER
  DELETE ON "lines"
  FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  DELETE
  FROM lines_buffer WHERE gid=OLD.id ;
 END
```

I havent tested it excessively, but i created, updated and deleted several lines and the buffer was always updated  (after refreshing/panning QGIS of course). So this could be an alternative where you have just one spatialite file to store the data and don't have to setup a PostGIS database...
[image]

Comment: A trigger will also work well for PostGIS, probably better than a view.

Comment: Yes, the performance while panning/zooming in qgis will probably be better.

Answer (score 3):

Just do

```
from qgis.analysis import QgsGeometryAnalyzer

# Select your layer
layer_ref = iface.activeLayer()
# Get layer tree root
root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()

# Prepare function that will act as slot
def save_after_edit(layer, qgsgeometrymap):
    output_filename = "output.shp"
    # Make buffer and save it in a shp
    QgsGeometryAnalyzer().buffer(layer_ref, output_filename, 500, False, False, -1)
    # If layer with a name 'buffer', remove it (only one layer 'buffer' allowed)
    if 'buffer' in [i.name() for i in QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayers().values()]:
        QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().removeMapLayer([i.id() for i in QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayers().values() if i.name() == "buffer"][0])
    # Add the created buffer and add it just below the layer at the top
    if 'buffer' not in [i.name() for i in QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayers().values()]:
        mylayer = QgsVectorLayer(output_filename, "buffer", "ogr")
        QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(mylayer, False)
        root.insertLayer(1, mylayer) # Position in the layer tree

# Use signal emitted from layer when you commit changes
# Other signals available at http://www.qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorLayer.html
layer_ref.committedGeometriesChanges.connect(save_after_edit)
```