# live ellipses around points in QGIS with orginal point still there?

Tags: qgis, buffer, ellipse

First of all I have found these: [Is there a way to have a 'live' buffer in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/169152/is-there-a-way-to-have-a-live-buffer-in-qgis) and [How to add a buffer in QGIS that updates itself](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/253326/how-to-add-a-buffer-in-qgis-that-updates-itself/) for creating a buffer which is updating itself when I move the points.

I used the geometry generator for creating the ellipses but with that the orginal points are gone.
My code  `make_ellipse($geometry,  "semi major axis", "semi minor axis",230,64)` (230 for azimut, semi axis are coming for the attribute table). I tried a bit with `make_point($x,$y) and code from above` but it didn't work.

How do I get the orginal points and the "live" ellipses around them?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using the little green plus to the right of the symbol-preview pane add a layer to the symbol, which by default should be a point representing your original feature, as long as you're working on a point layer.

[image]

Comment: wow that was actually too easy. was too focused on solving it with the code. thanks man